# WSO2 ESB JMS sample showing vfs transport configuration error

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to implement ESB as a JMS Consumer sample, given at WSO2 ESB documentation.
http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/ESB+as+a+JMS+Consumer

I have followed below steps:

1. configuring JMS listener and sender in

> ESB_Home\repository\conf\axis2\axis2.xml

2. copied all the jar file as mentioned
3. created a message queue in ActiveMQ using its web console.

**Below is my proxy service code:**

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="JMStoHTTPStockQuote" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

But still my proxy service is showing as faulty service. with the message:-

`Unable to configure the service JMStoHTTPStockQuote for the VFS transport: Service doesn't have configuration information for transport vfs. This service is being marked as faulty and will not be available over the VFS transport.`

As you can see I am not using VFS transport for my service and I have uncommented the code for VFS in axis2.xml but still I am getting this faulty exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your proxy configuration is not correct. If you want to listen to a JMS queue, you need to use the jms transport in your proxy service. In the link you have mentioned, the proxy service is given as below.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="JMStoHTTPStockQuoteProxy" transports="jms">
       <target>
           <inSequence>
               <property action="set" name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
           </inSequence>
           <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
           </endpoint>
           <outSequence>
               <send/>
           </outSequence>
       </target>
</proxy>
```

Here the transport is "jms". Please try with this config.

Comment: I have included activemq-all-5.8.0.jar, when i removed this jar file. It is working fine.